# How to convert unsigned long long to double

Tags: c

I have a random number generator as follows.

```
uint64_t s[ 2 ];

uint64_t next(void) { 
    uint64_t s1 = s[ 0 ];
    const uint64_t s0 = s[ 1 ];
    s[ 0 ] = s0;
    s1 ^= s1 << 23; // a
    return ( s[ 1 ] = ( s1 ^ s0 ^ ( s1 >> 17 ) ^ ( s0 >> 26 ) ) ) + s0; // b, c
}
```

I would like in fact to get doubles in the range (0,1).  One option is to do this in my code

```
#define M_RAN_INVM64 5.42101086242752217003726400434970855e-20
[..]
double u1;
u1 = next()*M_RAN_INVM64;
```

1. I am worried I am losing precision and also that this is platform dependent.
2. I don't want ever to get the values 0 or 1.

---

One option is to cast next() to signed long long, multiply by M_RAN_INVM64 and then add 0.5.  I can then add 2^(64)/2 to make sure I never get 0 I think.

Comment: `double d = your_unsigned_longlong * 1.0 / ULONG_LONG_MAX;`, and filter for 0 and 1 afterwards.

Comment: @user3477950 I am using  #define for speed purposes to avoid a division. I suppose I could just define a constant as 1.0 / ULONG_LONG_MAX  and give up on the #define?

Comment: @userXXXXX Yes there is, but that's premature optimization. Instead, turn on compiler optimization flags.

Comment: "I am losing precision". Well, if you have a 64-bit value and shove it into a 53 bit mantissa, you know what gonna happen? Some of them bits won't fit. "this is platform dependent." As long as your floating point is IEEE, you should be OK. If you need a truly robust solution, it's perhaps better to start with a robust PRNG. "I don't want ever to get the values 0 or 1." The easiest way is to check for these values and and filter them out.

Comment: @n.m. The platform dependency comes from my choosing 2^(-64) but now I think about it uint64_t is defined to be 64 bit so that is probably ok.

Comment: @user2179021 `unsigned long long` is _not_ defined to be 64 bit.  It must be _at least_ 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After accept answer:

`double` numbers are logarithmically distributed.  There are as many `double` 0.25 to 0.5 as there is 0.5 to 1.0 - assuming a base 2 `double`.

Assuming `double` is IEEE binary64:...

To get a *uniform* (linear) distribution of `double` in the range [0.0 to 1.0) only 2^53 values can be used.  So throw out 11 bits from the result of `next()`

```
uint64_t u1 = next();
u1 >>= 11;
// or
u1 &= 0x001FFFFFFFFFFFFF;
if (u1 == 0) ThrowOutZero();

// convert to (0.0 to 1.0)
double d = u1 / 9007199254740992.0;  // Divide by 2^53
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** In order to convert any positive `unsigned long long` to `long double` in the range (0, 1), you can use the following step factor:

```
 long double step = ((long double) 1.0) / ULLONG_MAX
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION** Perhaps you could take in account the limits of your system when working with floating point numbers.  What follows could help you to understand the floating point numbers in your system:

There is a portable way to obtain the smallest floating point number in the system where your program is compiled.

This can be achieved by using the standard library `<float.h>`.
With it you can use the following macro constants:

```
 FLT_MIN    // Smallest positive float number in your system  
 DBL_MIN    // Smallest positive double number in your system  
 LDBL_MIN   // Smallest positive long double number in your system
```

Also, you can take in account the "epsilon"-like constants, which gives you the information about the smallest positive number, of a given type, such that 1.0 != 1.0 + "epsilon".
This can helps you when you are trying to obtain numbers as close to 1.0 as possible, but still different:

```
FLT_EPSILON  
DBL_EPSILON  
LDBL_EPSILON
```

See, for example: [float.h (ANSI)](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/float.html)

Comment: I am a little confused. What I need is 1/ULLONG_MAX  isn't it?

Comment: @user2179021 Yes, but maybe I am not understanding what exactly you want to do. If the only thing you need is 1/ULLONG_MAX, then you can write `((long double) 1.0) / ULLONG_MAX`, to get it in the precision of `long double`.